# DesktopDatePicker onChange getting the old value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get the date of the date in a custom function in the onChange function.
The problem is that the function handleDatesChanged(), gets the previous date not the updated one.

```
 <DesktopDatePicker
              inputVariant="outlined"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="Return date"
              disabled={queryParameterUsed ? true : false}
              fullWidth
              name="endDate"
              onChange={(val) => {
                formik.setFieldValue("endDate", val);
                handleDatesChanged(); //the function that I fetch data based on the date updated
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              value={formik.values.endDate}
              inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    
            />



 const handleDatesChanged = () => {
    console.log(formik.values.endDate); //Prints 24/08/2022 (previous date) When in fact it should supposed to print to 28/08/2022
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setFieldValue` uses `useReducer` [under the hood](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/e677bea8181f40e6762fc7e7fb009122384500c6/packages/formik/src/Formik.tsx#L173). It is async and new value is not available immediately. The same applies to the `useState` hook. You can pass new value as parameter of handler:

```
onChange={(val) => {
  formik.setFieldValue("endDate", val);
  handleDatesChanged(val);
}

const handleDatesChanged = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
}
```